# What is the difference between Azure Stack Edge and Azure Stack Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-stack

I understand Azure Stack Edge is Hardware as a service. I Azure stack hub the extension of azure running on stack edge?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Stack Edge is an AI-enabled edge computing device with data storage and transfer capabilities into Microsoft Azure. From the portal you can request Azure Stack Edge.

Azure Stack Hub is like a smaller version of public Azure. You can run IaaS, PaaS (Azure App Service, MySQL, SQL, KeyVault, Event Hub, IoT Hub services, Event Grid). That targets customers who have Data sovereignty issues and latency issues. Users can use Azure services on their datacenter. Not like Stack Edge there is a huge investment for that. To build a stack hub you need minimum 4 nodes, TOR switched, FIs.